# How to make django form field without validation in administration

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I am learning django, currently I am working on django 1.9.
I have made a model named `experience`, which contains:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models


# Create your models here.

class Experience(models.Model):
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    present = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    joining_date = models.DateField()
    ending_date = models.DateField(null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.designation

    def __str__(self):
        return self.designation
```

Now, when I go to experience form, department and ending date must be required data. But I want that `department` and `ending_date` will pass null value and will not raise any validation error for these two attributes in `admin/experience` form.

How to do this ? Please help me.

Comment: So what is your problem? If it is required, it should be `blank=False`, and you won't be able to save instance without required data through form, but you will be able to create it manually through your code - `blank` is only for form validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change it to `ending_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)`